# Syntax trouble with C++

Tags: c++, syntax

I'm trying to take several letters as input and then print them in a ceratin order, here's an example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
void main()
{
    char aaa, bbb, ccc;
    cout << "input 3 letters ";
    cin >> aaa >> bbb >> ccc;

    cout <<  aaa "   " << bbb "   " << ccc endl;
}
```

I'm trying to make a space between each variable but it doesn't work.

This doesn't work either:

```
        cout <<  aaa <<"   " << bbb <<"   " << ccc endl;
```

PS: is not ok to ask questions about problems with syntax?

Comment: Missing `<<` before `endl`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `<<` between **everything** in the `cout` expression. You're still missing one before `endl`.

```
cout <<  aaa <<"   " << bbb <<"   " << ccc << endl;
                                           ^^
```

> PS: is not ok to ask questions about problems with syntax?

Yes, it's fine. But if the answer is that it's a simple error, the question will probably be closed since it won't be helpful to others.

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
cout <<  aaa << "   " << bbb << "   " << ccc << endl;
```